# vsftpd server allows different permissions than ssh

Tags: ssh, ftp, scp, vsftpd

I setup a vsftpd server on Debian 8.2, and haven't changed anything in the config file except for `local_root=/`.

When I try to upload a file using Filezilla to a directory I have group write permissions, it fails, with `550 Permission denied.`. This also happens when I try to upload a directory. I can't even upload files to my home directory.

The weird thing is, using `scp` I can upload the files and folders to the same locations, and it works fine, which leads me to believe that the problem lies within my configuration of vsftpd.

How can I fix this to allow me to upload files to directories that I am allowed to over ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [vsftpd.conf](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html) documentation

> write_enable
>   This controls whether any FTP commands which change the filesystem are allowed or not. These commands are: STOR, DELE, RNFR, RNTO, MKD, RMD, APPE and SITE.
>   Default: NO

You need to configure

```
write_enable=YES
```

and restart vsftpd.